# Getting react-native-google-signin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED while building React native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have installed the `react-native-google-signin` package. When im trying to build the the app its displaying this error:

```
/home/ish/Desktop/react-native/restaurant/node_modules/react-native-google-signin/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/googlesignin/RNGoogleSigninPackage.java:25: error: 
  method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
 1 error
:react-native-google-signin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':react-native-google-signin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
 > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: There was a deprecation a few versions of react-native ago that caused an issue with one of the libraries I was using. See if there's a newer version of `react-native-google-signin` or comment out the override @ line 25 in that file.

Comment: yes that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing  `@Override` did the trick